# Rename Shop by and clear all text in left side Magento2

Tags: magento2.4, layered-navigation, filter, product-list, navigation

I want to change the text SHOP BY and clear all from the left sidebar in the list page, Below is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: You can do it using a translation file in your custom theme/module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom theme add a translation file and translate the required string.

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\i18n\en_US.csv

Add below text in this translation file.

```
"Shop By","Filter Your Results"
"Clear All","Clear all filters"
"Remove This Item","Remove this filter"
```